# Export PHP interface to Typescript interface, or vice versa?

Tags: php, interface, typescript

I'm experimenting with Typescript, and at my current contract I code backend in PHP.

In a couple of projects I've written Typescript interfaces for the sort of AJAX responses my back end code gives so that the frontend developer (sometimes also me, sometimes someone else) knows what to expect and gets type checking and so on.

After writing a few such back end services it seems like the interface and related classes for the responses should exist on the PHP side too. And that makes me think that it'd be nice if I could write them in just one of the two languages and run some build-time tool (I'd invoke it with a gulp task, before the Typescript compiler runs) to export these interfaces to the other language.

Does such a thing exist? Is it possible? Practical?

(I realize PHP is not strongly typed, but if the interfaces were written in PHP there could be some type hinting there such as docstrings which the exporter recognizes and carries over to Typescript.)

Comment: Starting with php7 (and in hack) you have all basic and complex types(objects, arrays and callables were typehintable in php 5.x+) as typehints at your disposal (How they are enforced by the runtime is irrelevant for the export). So you could avoid parsing docblocks. Either way you could generate the AST using [php-parser](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser) and generate a typescript file based on that. Shouldn't be to complex. (I have no deeper knowledge of typescript, so I don't know how well the type systems match, but as it appears to be inspired by c# they should be somewhat compatible)

Comment: That's good to know. So all that remains is whether such a thing already exists.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use amazing [nikic/PHP-Parser](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser) to create a tool for converting selected PHP classes (those with `@TypeScriptMe` string in phpDoc) to TypeScript interfaces quite easily. The following script is really simple one but I think you can expand it and you can generate TypeScript interfaces automatically and possibly track changes through git.

**Example**

For this input:

```
<?php
/**
 * @TypeScriptMe
 */
class Person
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $name;

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    public $age;

    /**
     * @var \stdClass
     */
    public $mixed;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $propertyIsPrivateItWontShow;
}

class IgnoreMe {

    public function test() {

    }
}
```

you'll get:

```
interface Person {
  name: string,
  age: number,
  mixed: any
}
```

**Source codes**

**index.php:**

```
<?php

namespace TypeScript {

    class Property_
    {
        /** @var string */
        public $name;
        /** @var string */
        public $type;

        public function __construct($name, $type = "any")
        {
            $this->name = $name;
            $this->type = $type;
        }

        public function __toString()
        {
            return "{$this->name}: {$this->type}";
        }
    }

    class Interface_
    {
        /** @var string */
        public $name;
        /** @var Property_[] */
        public $properties = [];

        public function __construct($name)
        {
            $this->name = $name;
        }

        public function __toString()
        {
            $result = "interface {$this->name} {\n";
            $result .= implode(",\n", array_map(function ($p) { return "  " . (string)$p;}, $this->properties));
            $result .= "\n}";
            return $result;
        }
    }
}

namespace MyParser {

    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    require __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";

    use PhpParser;
    use PhpParser\Node;
    use TypeScript;

    class Visitor extends PhpParser\NodeVisitorAbstract
    {
        private $isActive = false;

        /** @var TypeScript/Interface_[] */
        private $output = [];

        /** @var TypeScript\Interface_ */
        private $currentInterface;

        public function enterNode(Node $node)
        {
            if ($node instanceof PhpParser\Node\Stmt\Class_) {

                /** @var PhpParser\Node\Stmt\Class_ $class */
                $class = $node;
                // If there is "@TypeScriptMe" in the class phpDoc, then ...
                if ($class->getDocComment() && strpos($class->getDocComment()->getText(), "@TypeScriptMe") !== false) {
                    $this->isActive = true;
                    $this->output[] = $this->currentInterface = new TypeScript\Interface_($class->name);
                }
            }

            if ($this->isActive) {
                if ($node instanceof PhpParser\Node\Stmt\Property) {
                    /** @var PhpParser\Node\Stmt\Property $property */
                    $property = $node;

                    if ($property->isPublic()) {
                        $type = $this->parsePhpDocForProperty($property->getDocComment());
                        $this->currentInterface->properties[] = new TypeScript\Property_($property->props[0]->name, $type);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public function leaveNode(Node $node)
        {
            if ($node instanceof PhpParser\Node\Stmt\Class_) {
                $this->isActive = false;
            }
        }

        /**
         * @param \PhpParser\Comment|null $phpDoc
         */
        private function parsePhpDocForProperty($phpDoc)
        {
            $result = "any";

            if ($phpDoc !== null) {
                if (preg_match('/@var[ \t]+([a-z0-9]+)/i', $phpDoc->getText(), $matches)) {
                    $t = trim(strtolower($matches[1]));

                    if ($t === "int") {
                        $result = "number";
                    }
                    elseif ($t === "string") {
                        $result = "string";
                    }
                }
            }

            return $result;
        }

        public function getOutput()
        {
            return implode("\n\n", array_map(function ($i) { return (string)$i;}, $this->output));
        }
    }

    ### Start of the main part


    $parser = new PhpParser\Parser(new PhpParser\Lexer\Emulative);
    $traverser = new PhpParser\NodeTraverser;
    $visitor = new Visitor;
    $traverser->addVisitor($visitor);

    try {
        // @todo Get files from a folder recursively
        //$code = file_get_contents($fileName);

        $code = <<<'EOD'
<?php
/**
 * @TypeScriptMe
 */
class Person
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $name;

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    public $age;

    /**
     * @var \stdClass
     */
    public $mixed;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $propertyIsPrivateItWontShow;
}

class IgnoreMe {

    public function test() {

    }
}

EOD;

        // parse
        $stmts = $parser->parse($code);

        // traverse
        $stmts = $traverser->traverse($stmts);

        echo "<pre><code>" . $visitor->getOutput() . "</code></pre>";

    } catch (PhpParser\Error $e) {
        echo 'Parse Error: ', $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

**composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "experiment/experiment",
    "description": "...",
    "homepage": "http://example.com",
    "type": "project",
    "license": ["Unlicense"],
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "MrX",
            "homepage": "http://example.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">= 5.4.0",
        "nikic/php-parser": "^1.4"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you can take a look at [TypeSchema](https://typeschema.org/) where you can generate a JSON format based on your PHP model and convert those JSON format back to different languages i.e. TypeScript, Java, etc. which could solve the problem which you described.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but in case you use Symfony as a framework to your project, you can use https://github.com/snakedove/php-to-typescript-converter. It adds a command, e.g. "ts-create-all" to your console, and lets you transform all POPOs, e.g. DTOs, of one folder, to TypeScript interfaces. Works one-way only. It has a special option to translate iterables to arrays of a given Type, which might be useful in some cases.